# MegaRaid Storage Manager Version to manage LSI 9260-8I through vSphere 4.1?

Tags: raid, vmware-vsphere, lsi

When I ran vSphere 4.0 I could use MSM 6.05 to manage my LSI card through the CIM provider, it would show up as a server to connect to.

Since upgrading to vSphere 4.1 I my vSphere host does not show up to manage, so I upgraded MSM to the latest 8.x release, and it still does not show up to manage.

Does anyone happen to know which MSM I can use to connect to the vSphere 4.1 CIM provider for LSI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to LSI support they do not support ESXi 4.x with MSM at present.  No ETA was given on support for it.